# Ordering HTML tables without Javascript?

Tags: php, html-table

I have a table with numerical values as the first column, however it is totally unordered :( I was wondering if there is a way to order the rows (highest number at the top) without using JavaScript?

Here is some code that maybe helpful on how I get the data:

```
$dh = opendir( $dirname ) or die("couldn't open directory");
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? (intval($_GET['start'])-1)*$bl_anzeige : 0;
while ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) {
if ($file{0} != '.') {
  $xzal=$i++;
  if($xzal>= $start && $xzal<$start+$pps2) {
  $filecrc = str_replace(".txt","",$file);
  $filesize = filesize("./storage/". $filecrc);
  $filesize = ($filesize / 1048576);
  $fh = fopen ("./files/".$file, r);
  $filedata= explode('|', fgets($fh));
<tr><td class="filelist" align=center bgcolor=#F9F9F9><?php echo $filedata[11];?></td>
```

Comment: If you are using a server-side language (which seems to be the case, judging by the comments in the answers), please say at least which one you are using and tag the question appropriately.

Comment: @Pekka, he had 0% when I mentioned how to review. He's a new user, so it was worth mentioning. I thought I was being polite, but out of context I can see how it might come off as brusque.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of printing each row out directly, save all rows together into an array and then use one of PHP's [many array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can sort the data via a server-side script.

If you want it live-sortable to a user without passing through a webserver, then you'll have to rely on JavaScript.

Comment: Nope i don't want it to be live I want it to be already sorted when the page loads :)

Comment: Any idea how to sort the data as it is grabbed from a series of text files

Comment: @King, I'm not a mind reader, I understand you're new to the [SO] community, so I'd like you to also review the [faq]. You'll need to post some code and provide a more details to your question, otherwise I wont be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about sorting a table in a static HTML page, many HTML editors have this feature. Or you could round-trip it to Excel.